# UILocalNotification with custom repeat Intervals other than NSCalendarUnits

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

UILocalNotification with custom repeat Intervals other than NSCalendarUnits, i want to repeat Events ping me after each 30 seconds and other time interval in my app,

please help!

Comment: You can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349444/uilocalnotification-every-30-seconds

Comment: hi, but i dont want to schedule many notifications like given in answer.