# iOS - Application Badge Disappears When Opened

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push, badge

I currently have an application that receives the correct badge number via push notification.  The backend server keeps track of the number of unread updates and sends the number in a push notification when an event happens.  The application badge number is then automatically set.  When the user clicks on a specific part of the application the badge count is decremented and synched with the backend.  This should all work in theory.  However, I can't seem to make the badge stay after the user opens the application after receiving the initial push.  How do I make the number stay, I looked into the issue and solving it using local notifications with the information located here: [iOS badge number live update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734078/ios-badge-number-live-update) but I am hoping to use a simpler solution.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application delegate, do you have any code that is clearing the badge count i.e.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

||

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response it turned out I did, really stupid mistake on my part thanks for the help!

Comment: No problems. Mark it as the answer so others know what to look for.

Comment: will do in about 6 minutes :P

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I was using Airship's SDK and instead of using their code for updating the badge count, I was using the iOS native code and that caused a glitch, especially right after a reinstallation and grant the push perms again.

Also, they have a reset method so if you are using them or any other library and that library has such capability, I would strongly advise against manually touching iOS push delegates, setting badge count number the classic way, etc. and seek to use the SDK's implementation instead.